# How to send Message & AVRO schema file together to JMS?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, avro, spring-jms, solace

```
@Component
public class GeneralTopicWriter {

@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

private Schema schema;
private DatumWriter<Customers> writer;

@Autowired
private EbxToCanonicalConverter ebxToCanonicalConverter;

public void sendAvroCustomerBinaryMessagetoTopic(List<Customer> customers, String topic) {
Customers convertedCustomers = ebxToCanonicalConverter.convert(customers);

jmsTemplate.send(topic, session -> {
BytesMessage bytesMessage = session.createBytesMessage();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
LOGGER.debug("Sending message " + convertedCustomers);
try {
writer.write(convertedCustomers, encoder);
encoder.flush();
out.close();
byte[] serializedBytes = out.toByteArray();
bytesMessage.writeBytes(serializedBytes);
} catch (Exception e) {
LOGGER.error("Error serializing Record "+convertedCustomers.toString(),e);
}
return bytesMessage;
});
}
@PostConstruct
private void initSchema() {
try {
schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(GeneralTopicWriter.class.getResourceAsStream("/avro/output/canonicalCustomer.avsc"));
} catch (IOException e) {
LOGGER.error("Can't find target schema", e);
}
writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);
}
}
```

Here we have logic to send Only AVRO message to the corresponding Topic But Can anyone help me to send Avro Schema and message together to the solace/Kafka/rabbitmq Topic.

Comment: Read the schema file as text. Append it to the byte array

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.